# Check input for number, default to a value if number not found

Tags: c++, loops, math

I'm trying to insert a statement into my program that checks to see if the value in the text file is a numerical value or not. If the value is a character(string) then it makes the variable equal 0. Basically I want my code to make all values that are not numbers default to 0.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <math.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#define M_PI 3.14159265358979323846 //pi
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double RecWidth, RecHeight, CirRadius, sumRadius, sumCircArea,sumCircumference,sumWidth, sumHeight, sumRecArea, sumPerimeter;
    int Age, Savings, sumAge, sumPeople,sumSavings;
    string FirstName, LastName;

    sumWidth = 0;
    sumHeight = 0;
    sumRecArea = 0;
    sumPerimeter = 0;
    sumRadius = 0;
    sumCircArea = 0;
    sumCircumference = 0;
    sumAge = 0;
    sumPeople = 0;
    sumSavings = 0;

    ifstream FileInput;
    ofstream FileOutput;

    FileOutput << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);

    FileInput.open("inData_Normal.txt");
    FileOutput.open("outputFile.txt");

    if (!FileInput.is_open())
    {
        return 1;
    }

    while (FileInput >> RecHeight >> RecWidth >> CirRadius >> FirstName >> LastName >> Age >> Savings)
    {
        sumHeight = sumHeight + RecHeight;
        sumWidth = sumWidth + RecWidth;
        sumRecArea = sumRecArea + (RecHeight * RecWidth);
        sumPerimeter = sumPerimeter + (2 * (RecHeight + RecWidth));
        sumRadius = sumRadius + CirRadius;
        sumCircArea = sumCircArea + (M_PI * CirRadius * CirRadius);
        sumCircumference = sumCircumference + (2 * M_PI * CirRadius);
        sumAge = sumAge + Age;
        sumSavings = sumSavings + Savings;
        sumPeople = sumPeople + 1;
    }

    FileOutput << "Rectangle:" << "\n";
    FileOutput << "The total Lengths = " << sumHeight << ", width = " << sumWidth <<", area = "<< sumRecArea << "," << "\n";
    FileOutput << "Perimeter = " << sumPerimeter << "\n" << "\n";
    FileOutput << "Circle:" << "\n";
    FileOutput << "The total Radius = "<< sumRadius << ", area = "<< sumCircArea <<", circumference = "<< sumCircumference << "\n"<< "\n";
    FileOutput << "Person:"<< "\n";
    FileOutput << "Total number of persons = " << sumPeople << "\n";
    FileOutput << "Total Age = "<< sumAge <<"\n";
    FileOutput << "The Total savings = "<< sumSavings;

    FileInput.close();
    FileOutput.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your `RecHeight`, `RecWidth`, ... as `std::string`. Then, in your `while` loop you have to insert:

```
sumHeight = sumHeight + std::atof(RecHeight.c_str());
sumWidth = sumWidth + std::atof(RecWidth.c_str());
```

and so on. `std::atof` is in the `<cstdlib>` library. It returns 0.0 if the
string's content is not convertable to `double`. Otherwise it returns the correponding value as a `double`.

Comment: Inside the `while` loop my lines now look like this 

`sumHeight = sumHeight + atof(RecHeight.c_str());` 

However, now I can't use my calculations as it is reading the the variables as string.

Comment: Do you mean you can't use your calculations inside the `while` loop? If this is the case, you have probably declared `sumHeight`, `sumWidth` as `string`. These have to be `double`. Only `RecHeight`, `RecWidth`, `CircRadius`, `Age` and `Savings` have to be `string`.

Comment: in the program I'm not using `sumHeight` and `sumWidth` for the total area.I'm using the variables `RecHeight` and `RecWidth` to calculate the area each time the loop repeats. The file I am reading from has 3 current iterations of the loop. I want to add the area's of 3 rectangles together but I want to be able to run the program even if one of the variables returns an invalid input

Comment: You could of course change everywhere `RecHeight` to `atof(RecHeight.c_str())` in your programm. However, if your programm is already very long, this would not be a good solution. Then, how about declaring `std::string strHeight, strWidth, strRadius, strAge, strSav` just before the while loop. Then, in the `while` loop: `while(FileInput >> strHeight >> strWidth >> ...) {RecHeight = atof( strHeight.c_str() ); RecWidth = atof( strWidth.c_str() ); ...}`. Then you could keep all your further calculations unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a quick hack you can change the while statement as follows:

```
while (FileInput >> RecHeight)
{
    FileInput >> RecWidth >> CirRadius >> FirstName >> LastName >> Age >> Savings;
...
}
```

This will allow you to check for a new record in your while statement (RecHeight must be a valid float for this code to work). Then all the rest of the values will default to 0 for any missing or invalid input.